# How can I use the same socket in a loop?

Tags: python, sockets, reset

I received a list of IPs and ports of differents clients. This clients are listening and always the conection will be accept.So I have to make a for to get all IPs and ports to send to the clients a txt file. I have tried with 2 clients. The firs one, the file sent succesfully, but with the next client never transfers the file.
I have read some posts and I think that it can be due to use the same socket quickly with the same port and IP (I can't change the port)

```
try:
    st = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print "Error al crear socket TCP"
    sys.exit()

try:
    st.connect((str(ipx),int(portx)))
except socket.error:
    print "Error al realizar la conexion TCP con el cliente de 
        puerto " + str(portx)
    sys.exit()
tam = os.stat(sys.argv[2]).st_size
nom = sys.argv[2]
mssg = nom + " " + str(tam)
st.send(mssg)
try:
    st.settimeout(3)
    resplyc = st.recv(1024)
except socket.timeout:
    print "Error: No hay respuesta por parte del cliente " + ipx + " 
        en el puerto " + str(portx)
    st.close()
    sys.exit()


st.send(fich.read())
try:
    st.settimeout(10)
    resplyc2= st.recv(1024)
except socket.timeout: # I always get this exception
    print "Error en la transferencia con cliente " + ipx
    print "con puerto "+portx
    st.close()
    sys.exit()

st.close()
print 'socket closed'
```

This is inside of a for loop. The conection and the delievery with the first client is always succesfully, but when I conect with the second, always the last exception is thrown.

Comment: what exception are you getting? and where is the for loop?

Comment: `st.send(fich.read())` What is `fich`?

Comment: @JacobIRR "Error en la tranferencia con cliente" this exception and this si the body of the loop, all the code is inside it

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it send the file, fich is the file

Comment: `st.send(fich.read())` Reads the entire file the first time through. The following iterations, there is nothing left to read. Before the loop, read the contents into a buffer `file_contents = fich.read()`, then send that: `st.send(file_contents)`